# Extracting the int from a byte retrieved from a lock in device

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, byte, device

I'm trying to get the time constant from a lock in device, I use this code:

```
self.ser.write("OFLT?\r\n".encode())
self.ser.write("++read\r\n".encode())
print (self.ser.readline())
```

which prints `b'9\n'`. I want only the 9 from this, but I can't seem to get it out. I have tried:

```
a = self.ser.readline()
print (type(a))
print ("a is: " + a.decode())
```

which results in

```
<class 'bytes'>
a is:
```

Only giving me a blank space. I tried to separately run this code as

```
a = b'9\n'
print ("a is " + a.decode())
```

Which does print

```
a is 9
```

Comment: What does your read function look like? Also, I don't quite understand what you are trying to do , but that might be me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your full code looks like this:

```
...
print (self.ser.readline())
a = self.ser.readline()
...
```

It seems to be that `ser` is a file object, so once you've printed out that line, the pointer advances to the next line and you can't read it again.

Try removing that print statement. Also, if you want to remove the trailing newline, you can use `a.decode().rstrip()`.